# Why is Eclipse using c:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\javaw.exe in Windows?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I installed java in C:\java\jdk1.7.0_51 location. but Eclipse using c:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\javaw.exe.

I am getting problem "Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6"  while maven build. I saw one of the solutions that add below line in eclipse.ini

```
-vm C:\java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe
```

So, I added and placed in eclipse.ini, after Eclipse not opening by clicking the eclipse.exe instead of that it showing one window, that having two!

[image: Please find image]

-vm parameters one I added and other -vm `c:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\javaw.exe`. So after removed "`-vm C:\java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin`" from eclipse.ini then it working again. If I am wrong, that mean it is using c:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\javaw.exe.

Why it is using from `c:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\javaw.exe`, why it not using `C:\java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe`?

How to change to `C:\java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe`?

Comment: Edit your PATH and JAVA_HOME environment variable!?

Comment: You appear to be trying to use `javaw.ext` - did you mean `javaw.exe`?

Comment: My java home is JAVA_HOME=C:\java\jdk1.7.0_51

Comment: PATH=%PATH%;C:\java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;

Answer (score 2):

Place the -vm behind openFile, and the path in a **new line**

openFile
**-vm** 
**C:\java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw**
--launcher.appendVmargs

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have your path variable with the desired java before the System32 folder. Something like

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;
```

or after seeing your comment, to

```
PATH=C:\java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;%PATH%;
```

when typing e.g. java.exe, the program will be searched in the location defined in PATH in the order of defining. That's why the order counts

If the system32 is before your java path, it will use the SDK as definied in your registry key, which is the latest installed java, if this is not what you want you can fix it by re-ordering the locations in the PATH variable

UPDATE with respect to the comments,

with the path properly set, try removing the absolute file from eclipse.ini, leaving only javaw.exed

Comment: Because a full path is given in the -vm argument, there is no need to have this jdk in the PATH

Comment: true, my complete idea was to make a change, and lean on javaw.exe without the full path, edited in an answer

Answer (score 1):

I'll add yet another answer since I don't see one that I find 100% correct - its not really important where exactly you put the lines in the ini file, just as long as you stick to two rules:

1. don't put the lines half-way in the middle of another parameter configuration
2. the -vm and the path need to be on two separate lines

so if you simply put

```
-vm
c:/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javaw.exe
```

at the very top of the eclipse.ini file you should be fine, Eclipse should boot up and it should not attempt to want to put a default -vm line in there itself anymore. Assuming the path is valid of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit it in

```
Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs
```

You can specify default jre for newly created projects, while having different JREs installed.

Comment: The installed jre's are for running projects, not eclispe itself.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the question properly